# Thunks not dispatching

Tags: meteor, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Can anyone see what's wrong with my thunks?  The inner code is never called but the outer code is.  This is an example thunk:

```
export function selectCustomer(customerId) {
    console.log("This appears in the console fine");
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        console.log("This doesn't.. why don't you run..?");
        dispatch(loadCustomerToEdit(customerId));
    }
};
```

This is how I'm wiring it up to the  component events:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import CustomerEditForm from './CustomerEditForm.jsx';
import { editCustomer, selectCustomer, selectNewCustomer, saveCustomer } from '../redux/action_creators.jsx';


export const CustomerContainer = React.createClass({   
    componentWillMount() {
        const customerId = FlowRouter.getParam('_id');

        if (customerId) {
            this.sub = Meteor.subscribe('CustomerCompany.get', customerId, this.setCustomerInState);
        } else {
            this.props.selectNewCustomer();
        }
    },

    setCustomerInState() {
        console.log("setCustomerInState");
        this.props.selectCustomer(FlowRouter.getParam('_id'));
    },

    // Snip

    render() {
        console.log("CustomerContainer.render()", this.props);
        if (this.sub && !this.sub.ready) {
            return (<h1>Loading</h1>);
        }
        return (
            <CustomerEditForm
                customer = {this.props.customer}
                onChange = {this.props.onChange}
                onSave = {this.props.onSave}
                errors = {this.props.customer.errors}
                isValid = {this.props.customer.isValid}
                salesRegionOptions={SalesRegions.find().fetch()}
            />
        );
    }
});

CustomerContainer.propTypes = {
    customer: PropTypes.object,
    onSave: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    selectCustomer: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    selectNewCustomer: PropTypes.func.isRequired   
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log("CustomerContainer.mapStateToProps", state)
    return {
        customer: state.userInterface.customerBeingEdited
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    //console.log("CustomerContainer.mapDispatchToProps", Actions.customerSave)
    return {
        onSave: saveCustomer,
        onChange: editCustomer,
        selectCustomer,
        selectNewCustomer
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
)(CustomerContainer);
```

And this is my store setup:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers.jsx';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const middleware = [ thunk ]

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(...middleware)(createStore)
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer)

export default store;
```

You'll no doubt recognise a lot of this code as it is adapted from the excellent [examples in the redux documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/Examples.html).

The `selectCustomer` function is called, so `mapDispatchToProps` seems to have wired the `selectCustomer` function to the component, it's just that the method returned by `selectCustomer` isn't called.

Comment: What's your Redux version? The `createStore` API changed a bit in Redux >= 3.1.0, and is now:

`const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);`

Comment: Ah, that's good knowledge @mstoiber, thank you.  I'm on React 14.7,  Redux 3.3.1 and Redux-Thunk 1.0.3.  I just switched to the new syntax but still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `mapDispatchToProps` function. react-redux does not automatically wrap your action creators if you pass it a function, only if you pass it an object! (or if you bind them manually with `bindActionCreators`)

Try changing your `connect` call to this, and it should work:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, {
  onSave: saveCustomer,
  onChange: editCustomer,
  selectCustomer,
  selectNewCustomer
})(YourComponent);
```

Comment: That was the syntax I had originally, but the Redux examples move the dispatching to the action methods (I think they are called action creators), so if you look at my `selectCustomer` method that does the dispatch.  From the docs, this is an example of the container: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/shopping-cart/containers/ProductsContainer.js and this is an example of the action: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/shopping-cart/actions/index.js.  They aren't doing the dispatch in `mapDispatchToProps` there which is what I was trying to replicate

Comment: Right, but your `selectCustomer` function somehow needs access to that `dispatch` – and it gets that through being dispatched. Now, the other option you have is to simply have an object in the `connect` function, which is what the redux example does. I've edited the answer above to reflect that!

Comment: Thank you, that's it.  Put another way, I needed to actually call `mapDispatchToProps` in my original code, i.e. to stick `()` on the end and  do `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps()
)(CustomerContainer);`

Comment: Yes that works too, but is not a pattern I've seen around :-) Glad to help!

Comment: Extra kudos to @mstoiber here as he solved this even though I'd forgotten to include the broken `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps()
)(CustomerContainer);` line in my original code example

Comment: I've binned `mapDispatchToProps`, you're right, it's not helping anything as it behaves differently to `mapStateToProps`

Comment: Thanks, really glad I could help!